# Por que jmimemagic lanza exepcion con archivos sql?

Tags: java, pruebas-unitarias

Hola trabajo con Play Framework 1.4 y Java, Tengo una clase Test con UnitTest que prueba una clase que valida archivos con jmimemagic, pero al momento de validar archivos con extensión sql lanza la excepción MagicMatchNotFoundException

Por que jmimemagic lanza está excepción con los archivos sql?

```
net.sf.jmimemagic.MagicMatchNotFoundException
at net.sf.jmimemagic.Magic.getMagicMatch(Magic.java:368)
at net.sf.jmimemagic.Magic.getMagicMatch(Magic.java:240)
at sui.validateFileTest$Utils.validateFile(validateFileTest.java:41)
at sui.validateFileTest.validateFileFormatInvalidTest(validateFileTest.java:66)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner$StartPlay$2$1.evaluate(PlayJUnitRunner.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner.run(PlayJUnitRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:105)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:94)
at play.test.TestEngine.run(TestEngine.java:188)
at controllers.TestRunner$1.doJobWithResult(TestRunner.java:101)
at controllers.TestRunner$1.doJobWithResult(TestRunner.java:1)
at play.jobs.Job$2.apply(Job.java:208)
at play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransaction(JPA.java:258)
at play.db.jpa.JPA.withinFilter(JPA.java:217)
at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin$TransactionalFilter.withinFilter(JPAPlugin.java:298)
at play.jobs.Job.withinFilter(Job.java:185)
at play.jobs.Job.call(Job.java:204)
at play.jobs.Job$1.call(Job.java:119)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Utils class**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public static class Utils {

public static List<String> getFormats() {

    String[] formats = { "pdf", "doc", "docx", "csv", "xls", "xlsx", "odt", "jpg", "png", "jpeg" };

    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(formats);

    return list;

}

public static void validateFile(Validation validation, File file)
        throws MagicParseException, MagicMatchNotFoundException, MagicException {

    if (file == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("File is null");

    Magic magic = new Magic();
    MagicMatch match = magic.getMagicMatch(file, false);

    if (file.length() == 0)
        validation.addError("file", "File is empty");

    if (!getFormats().contains(match.getExtension()))
        validation.addError("file", "Format not valid");

}
}
```

**Test class**

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import java.io.File;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import net.sf.jmimemagic.Magic;
import net.sf.jmimemagic.MagicException;
import net.sf.jmimemagic.MagicMatch;
import net.sf.jmimemagic.MagicMatchNotFoundException;
import net.sf.jmimemagic.MagicParseException;
import play.data.validation.Validation;
import play.test.UnitTest;

public class validateFileTest extends UnitTest {

private Validation validation;

@Before
public void init() {

validation = Validation.current();
validation.clear();
}

@Test
public void validateFileFormatInvalidTest()
    throws MagicParseException, MagicMatchNotFoundException, MagicException {

File file = new File("./docs/file-sql.sql");
Utils.validateFile(validation, file);

assertThat(validation.hasErrors(), is(true));
}

@Test
public void validateFileFormatValidTest() throws MagicParseException, MagicMatchNotFoundException, MagicException {

File file = new File("./docs/file-pdf.pdf");
Utils.validateFile(validation, file);

assertThat(validation.hasErrors(), is(false));

}

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void validateFileNullTest() throws MagicParseException, MagicMatchNotFoundException, MagicException {

Utils.validateFile(validation, null);

}

@Test
public void validateFileEmptyTest() throws MagicParseException, MagicMatchNotFoundException, MagicException {

File file = new File("./docs/file-empty.docx");
Utils.validateFile(validation, file);

assertThat(validation.hasErrors(), is(false));
}
}
```

Comment: Me parece que es por el file, si existe el file? if (file == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("File is null");  agrega también un file.exists(), la ruta se ve extraña ./docs/file?

Comment: Hola, le hice un debug y se cae exactamente en esta linea 
 MagicMatch match = magic.getMagicMatch(file, false);
en el metodo getMagicMatch

Comment: y los archivos estan dentro del mismo proyecto por eso declaro la ruta relativa

Comment: la ruta relativa sería docs/file no? sin el ./

Comment: La ruta absoluta es sin el ./ la cual seria /myapp/docs/nombre del archivo, y la relativa es con ./

Comment: Si entiendo eso, sin embargo en java hace lo siguiente /myapp/./docs/nombrearchivo  por lo que sugiero hagas esto: File file = new File("docs/file-sql.sql"); debería ser así.

Comment: Me aparece que el archivo no existe colocando la ruta asi como indicas

Comment: Revisa tu ruta relativa con file.getAbsolutePath() y revisa si estas colocando las rutas correctas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jmimemagic no soporta algunas extensiones de archivos motivo por el cual arroja esta excepción MagicMatchNotFoundException, para solucionarlo tuve que encerrar en un multicatch metodo "magic.getMagicMatch(file, false)" para capturar la excepción y agregar el error a las validaciones del campo "file".

```
public static class Utils {

    public static List<String> getFormats() {

        String[] formats = { "pdf", "doc", "docx", "csv", "xls", "xlsx", "odt", "jpg", "png", "jpeg" };

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(formats);

        return list;

    }

    public static void validateFile(Validation validation, File file) {

        if (file == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("File is null");

        Magic magic = new Magic();
        MagicMatch match;
        try {

            match = magic.getMagicMatch(file, false);

            if (file.length() == 0)
                validation.addError("file", "File is empty");

            if (!getFormats().contains(match.getExtension()))
                validation.addError("file", "Format not valid");

        } catch (MagicParseException | MagicMatchNotFoundException | MagicException e) {
            validation.addError("file", "Format not valid");
        }

    }
}
```